# Eclipse and Xdebug does not parse additional ini files in /etc/php5/conf.d

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I have setup Eclipse 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 11.4 for AMD64 and [Xdebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug).

Eclipse was installed with zip download from eclipse.org.
PHP and Xdebug were setup with [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool).

When I run the PHP script in the shell they will use the `/etc/php5/php.ini` file and parse additional ini files in `/etc/php5/conf.d/`.

When I run in Eclipse (run mode or debug mode) it will only parse `php.ini` and no additional ini files.

Basically, all extensions, are not loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an intentional bug.
PDT executes php with "-n" option always. It makes additional ini files unavailable.
see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339547 
also https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347618

BTW, you'll be able to add a shell script which trims "-n" option as PHP Executable.(Preferences>PHP>PHP Executables)
For example,

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = "-n" ]; then
  shift;
fi
/usr/bin/php $*
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just switched from windows to ubuntu as developing platform. I was getting lost.

Answer (score 2):

The answer @atlanto gives as a work around did and does still work, but recent version of Eclipse (I'm on Neon) has a fix that may work for you if you don't mind using the `php.ini` and `conf.d` set by default for the php executable.

The failing to load additional files only happens now if you put in an explicit `php.ini` file when defining a PHP executable.   **Leave this blank** and **check the box** `Use system default php.ini configurate`.

[image]

Now if you use the location/php.ini that was specified as default when the executable was built, it will respect scanning of `conf.d` directories.

Here's how to check if your `php` has scanning `conf.d` enable and where the approriate default location is:

```
    php -i "(command-line 'phpinfo()')" | grep "Configure Command"
```

You  should see something like:

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php5/5.6.29_5' 
'--localstatedir=/usr/local/var' '--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6' 
'--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6' 
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d' 
'--mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.29_5/share/man' 

... and so on...
```

The items that matter are:

- `with-config-file-path`: this where it will look for your `php.ini` file
- `with-config-file-scan-dir`: this is the `conf.d` that will be scanned

If you still wish to choose a different in location than the default for the executable your options are:

- Inline the module directives from  and file in `conf.d` into your alternate `php.ini`
- Rebuild php and set the above options to your new location as default
- Use the wrapper script @atlanto indicates